# Bright light in sky that slowly faded away

Tags: star, light

North Carolina June 5th 2021 at about 1:45 a.m. my boyfriend walked to me to my car just to see a bright like just above the tree line. Didn’t think anything of it. Finished our goodnight talk and looked back at the light. It was still there and we watched it slowly move and fade away. It looked as thought it was the northern star but extremely brighter. It did not fade behind the tree line but faded away in a straight line from where it was just sitting stationary.

Comment: No astronomical object can explain a star-like light that fades.  It is most likely the landing headlights of a distant aircraft, which seem like a bright star when the aircraft is pointing them towards you, but fade as it turns.  It often looks like a bright star that fades without moving. There are other possibilities, but none of an astronomical nature. As this isn't an astronomical phenomenum, it is not suited for Astronomy Stack Exchange, and I vote to close.

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE, and thanks indeed for asking. Please don't be disappointed by the close-votes, this is how the site works. JamesK actually answered your question. He also correctly stated that although it looks like an astronomy question at first sight,  according to the community guidelines, it is not.